# Iniciar con modo kiosko en win 10 y chrome

Tags: windows10, chrome

Tengo un site del tipo catalogo con una pantalla touchscreen. En windows 7 sencillamente creaba un acceso directo agregando en propiedades/destino : "c\xxx\xxx\chrome" --kiosk http://170.0.0.25

Ahora estoy haciendo lo mismo pero en Windows 10 .. lo anterior no funcionó , aunque encontré una forma que funcione del siguiente modo : "c\xxx\xxx\chrome" --kiosk "http://170.0.0.25" --kiosk

Si ejecuto el acceso directo desde el escritorio , la web que llamo se muestra correctamente, en modo kiosko .

La idea es que al prender el ordenador se realice un autologin y ejecute el chrome en modo kiosko. En windows 7 solo puse el acceso directo al inicio y siempre funcionó. En windows 10 .... cuando se inicia , hace el autologin , pero me llama al chrome sin el modo kiosko .... si ejecuto el acceso directo desde el escritorio ..funciona bien ... no entiendo las causas. Ayuda por favor !!

Answer (score 1):

no he tenido suerte por este lado, pero si en otro foro. Sencillamente accedí con el usuario administrador a los programas de inicio y me encontré que ya cargaba chrome ... antes de la llamada que yo hacia, aunque no aparecia por shell:startup.

Lo elimine del inicio, cree un .bat con la ruta del chrome y el modificador kiosk , y **lo cargué como tarea programada al inicio**. Funciona ok, ojalá sirva para otros que necesiten estas cosas.

win + R

`taskschd.msc`

Ejecutar "at logon any user"